# Spark shuffle metrics

Tags: apache-spark, shuffle

I am looking at the even logs of a spark job. There is a metric called shuffle write time, when I add up all the shuffle write times, I get 1846856495 for a job that ran 15 seconds.

My question is,  what unit is this time in? It does not seem to be milli or micoseconds

Comment: can u share some more logs ?

Comment: You can get all the metric values even from spark UI.

Comment: Shuffle Write Metrics":{"Shuffle Bytes Written":5991746,"Shuffle Write Time":12773576,"Shuffle Records Written":1000000},"Input Metrics":{"Bytes Read":0,"Records Read":0},"Output Metrics":{"Bytes Written":0,"Records Written":0},"Updated Blocks":[]}}

Comment: I Know I can get metrics from spark ui , but I want to calculate bandwidth in a script and need to make use of the logs.

Answer (score -1):

The unit of time for shufflewrite*10<sup>-6</sup> is millisecond. 
[Time spent blocking on writes to disk or buffer cache. The value is expressed in nanoseconds.](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html)